# How to get all source IP addresses connected to a specific port of a Docker service

Tags: docker, netstat

For direct services on the server, you can view the source IPs of the current connection service through the following command

```
netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | grep 8090| awk '{print $5}' |cut -d: -f1|sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

But it seems that the source IP connected to the Docker service cannot be checked. How can I check it?